# rjb `import': can't create Java VM (RuntimeError) from app/java/test.rb:4:in `<main>'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rjb

I'm trying to import java code in my rails application.

but when I include a 'rjb' gem in my gem file and write a simple test code,

it shows this problem:

```
`import': can't create Java VM (RuntimeError)
from app/java/test.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

my test.rb file is:

```
require 'rjb'

puts "access java.util.UUID via RJB"
puts Rjb::import('java.util.UUID').randomUUID().toString()
```

I don't know what to do now..
Any help will be immensely appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is some information in the top "jvm is required" section at:

http://rjb.rubyforge.org/

...that might help you.

What OS are you running? Do you have a JVM installed?

-- Keith